# NoMethodError in Devise when calling Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise gem for users. I have a contents_controller.rb and I want to display content.name in my application.html.erb but there seems to be a conflict with Devise when I do this. When I load the page the data is rendered but when I click login, to access editing abilities, I get a `` NoMethodError in Devise::Sessions#new undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass ``. My code is listed below.

Application.html.erb :

```
<% @contents.each do |content| %>
 <a class="navbar-brand" ><%= content.name %></a>
<%end%>
```

Contents_controller.rb :

```
class ContentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_content, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @contents = Content.all
    @services = Service.all.order("created_at asc")
    @portfolios = Portfolio.all.order("created_at asc")
  end

  def new
    @content = Content.new
  end

  def create
    @content = Content.new content_params

    if @content.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "content Created!"
    else
      render 'new', notice: "Sorry content failed to create!!!"
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @content.update content_params
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You Updated: #{@content.name}."
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @content.destroy
    redirect_to content_path
  end

  private

  def content_params
    params.require(:content).permit(:name, :header_title, :services_title, :slogan_title, :about_title, :about_description, :contact_title, :contact_subtitle, :fb_username, :ig_username, :twitter_username, :in_username, :pin_username)
  end

  def find_content
    @content = Content.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Can someone please help me explain why this is happening and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you please share your sessions_controller and sessions/new.html.erb content?
When you get this error, along with this error, you will see which line its coming from. Go to that line and see which object is not proper.

Comment: I don't have a sessions controller. I am not sure if devise gives me access to it. I can get the Sessions#new html partial.? and the error is on the line where I have @contents.each